# XML Parsing in Python-- avoid multiple tag values in sub root

Tags: python

Actuvally am having below XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
        <soapenv:Body> 
                <c:RetriveByVehicleLineModelYearResponse xmlns:a="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0" xmlns:b="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/SingleOrderEdit/v1.0" xmlns:c="urn:ford/interface/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2"> 
                        <c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                                <a:VehicleLineId>13001</a:VehicleLineId> 
                                <a:ModelYear>2014</a:ModelYear> 
                                <a:LegacyColumn>12</a:LegacyColumn> 
                                <a:LegacyValue>178       </a:LegacyValue> 
                                <a:SalesCode>W78</a:SalesCode> 
                                <a:MappingId>41859</a:MappingId> 
                                <a:MappingSeq>0</a:MappingSeq> 
                                <a:MappingDirection>B</a:MappingDirection> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15615</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5K8</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>178 /4521MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15615</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5K8_second time</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>178 /4521MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                        </c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                        <c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                                <a:VehicleLineId>13001</a:VehicleLineId> 
                                <a:ModelYear>2014</a:ModelYear> 
                                <a:LegacyColumn>12</a:LegacyColumn> 
                                <a:LegacyValue>190       </a:LegacyValue> 
                                <a:SalesCode>W90</a:SalesCode> 
                                <a:MappingId>41860</a:MappingId> 
                                <a:MappingSeq>0</a:MappingSeq> 
                                <a:MappingDirection>B</a:MappingDirection> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15616</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5MA</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>190 /4826MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                        </c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                </c:RetriveByVehicleLineModelYearResponse> 
        </soapenv:Body>
```

My expected Output is:

```
WersCode 
AA5K8 
AA5MA
```

For this am using below Code:

```
import glob   
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

Fatfile = open('#Var_SOE_VLIS_Response_Output\\Sales_to_Wers_Code2.txt', 'a') 
try: 
   tree = ET.parse('#Var_ENG_Response_Files\\SoapResponse1.xml')     
   Fatfile.write('1111') 
   WersCodeList = tree.findall('.//{urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0}PortInstalledOptionFeature') 
   Fatfile.write('\n2222') 
  # x = len(WersCodeList) 
  # Fatfile.write(x) 
   Fatfile.write('\n333') 
   for WersCode in WersCodeList : 
         Fatfile.write('\n444') 
         WersCode = WersCode.find('.//{urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0}WersCode') 
         Fatfile.write('\n') 
         Fatfile.write(WersCode.text) 
except : 
    Fatfile.write(' \nsorry') 
Fatfile.write(' \nSuccess')
```

" 
But i Could not able to get the all  "PortInstalledOptionFeature" child values.. The findall methos returns empty list...

Please help me on this sir.....

Comment: Could you please state how are you trying to do this? If you have no idea where to start, please take a look to the xml parsing libraries built into Python.

Comment: Am using same packages from Pyton.. am using ElementTree library and in that using parse method and findall method .. but i could not get exact solution sir... Please help me

Comment: Try to get some small fragment of code that people here can review...

Comment: Hi Dsign,- Please look above is my xml file and my code .. please help on this sir.. am struggling a lot sir..

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlText)
>>> for country in tree.findall('./country'):
        print(country.attrib['name'])
        print(country.find('./rank').text)
        print(country.find('./year').text)
        print(country.find('./gdppc').text)

Liechtenstein
1
2008
141100
Singapore
4
2011
59900
Panama
68
2011
13600

>>> # Or as a list of dictionaries
>>> [{'name': country.attrib['name'], 'rank': country.find('./rank').text, 'year': country.find('./year').text, 'gdppc': country.find('./gdppc').text} for country in tree.findall('./country')]
[{'gdppc': '141100', 'name': 'Liechtenstein', 'rank': '1', 'year': '2008'},
 {'gdppc': '59900', 'name': 'Singapore', 'rank': '4', 'year': '2011'},
 {'gdppc': '13600', 'name': 'Panama', 'rank': '68', 'year': '2011'}]
```